# MongoDB w/ PyMongo on Heroku -- error: no module named pymongo

Tags: mongodb, heroku, flask, pymongo

I am making a heroku app using Flask with a mongoDB backend. I am using pymongo as my driver but when I push my code to git, it crashes and spits out this error:

```
2014-04-05T09:56:36.301695+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named pymongo
```

The web-app works locally and pymongo works completely fine in that scenario. What do I have to do to have pymongo recognized on heroku's servers?

Thansks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to make Heroku aware of PyMongo as a requirement. The easiest way to do this is my adding `pymongo==x.x` to your [`requirements.txt` file](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#specify-dependencies-with-pip).

If you are using a `setup.py` script instead of `requirements.txt`, add `'pymong==x.x',` to the `install_requires` argument to `setup`.

In both cases, make sure to replace `x.x` with the appropriate version number.